# When assigning a command output to a variable, the new lines are replaced by white spaces

Tags: bash, sed, grep, newlines

I have a file and the idea is to grep the content following a pattern ("create mode") and to store this content in a bash variable in order to use it then in a curl statement. I have the commands working but the problem is that when the output is assigned to the variable, the new lines were replaced by white spaces.

Example of file

```
...
example1
example2
 create mode 100644 repo/linux-image-5.4.0-89-generic_5.4.0-89.100_amd64.deb
 create mode 100644 repo/linux-modules-5.4.0-89-generic_5.4.0-89.100_amd64.deb
 create mode 100644 repo/python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
 create mode 100644 repo/python3.8_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
example3
example4
...
```

I need to grep **only** the ubuntu packages and store them into a bash variable `var`. The idea is to keep the format (With the `\n`)

I tried using grep, sed and modifiying the output with printf and assigning the output to a variable.

Example using  `grep and printf`

```
test_variable=$( cat file.txt | grep "create mode" )
var=$( printf '%s\n' "${test_variable//' create mode 100644 repo/'/}" )
echo $var
repo/linux-image-5.4.0-89-generic_5.4.0-89.100_amd64.deb repo/linux-modules-5.4.0-89-generic_5.4.0-89.100_amd64.deb repo/python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb repo/python3.8_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
```

When I used the same printf command but without assigning the output to a variable, the result was:

```
linux-image-5.4.0-89-generic_5.4.0-89.100_amd64.deb
linux-modules-5.4.0-89-generic_5.4.0-89.100_amd64.deb
python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
python3.8_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
```

I tried using  `tr` and others for troubleshooting this.

Other example using  `sed`

```
sed -e '/create mode/!d' file.txt
 create mode 100644 repo/linux-image-5.4.0-89-generic_5.4.0-89.100_amd64.deb
 create mode 100644 repo/linux-modules-5.4.0-89-generic_5.4.0-89.100_amd64.deb
 create mode 100644 repo/python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
 create mode 100644 repo/python3.8_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
```

That is ok. But when i tried to assign this output to a variable, the newlines were replaced by a white space.

```
var=$( sed -e '/create mode/!d' file.txt )
echo $var
create mode 100644 repo/linux-image-5.4.0-89-generic_5.4.0-89.100_amd64.deb create mode 100644 repo/linux-modules-5.4.0-89-generic_5.4.0-89.100_amd64.deb create mode 100644 repo/python3.8-minimal_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb create mode 100644 repo/python3.8_3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Could you help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you use `echo "$var"` it will work fine:

```
$ valor=$( cat <<EOF
> hola
> adios
> EOF
> )
$ echo $valor
hola adios
$ echo "$valor"
hola
adios
$
```